# Evitar que los valores char de un arreglo bidimensional se repitan, para encriptarse

Tags: c#, array, poo

El programa pide por medio de un array unidimensional n caracteres estos se pueden repetir `caracteres[conteo]`, luego con un array bidimensional pide n caracteres a encriptar `car_encri[conteo, 0]` y sus respectivos caracteres por lo que se encriptara `car_encri[conteo, 1]`, pero cada que se agregue un caracter no debe repetirse, en todo caso se repitiera debe volver a preguntar el caracter, de igual manera con el caracter por el que se encriptara no debe ser igual a otro ingresado previamente, ni debe ser alguno de los primeros caracteres del array unidimensional `caracteres[conteo]`. Necesito de su ayuda por favor les anexo mi codigo, espero puedan ayudarme es un programa C# en consola

```
class Ejer_Encriptar
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Numero de caracteres: ");
        int num_car = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (num_car > 0)
        {
            char[] caracteres = new char[num_car];
            int conteo = 0;
            for (; conteo < num_car; conteo++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}: ", conteo + 1);
                caracteres[conteo] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (caracteres[conteo] == ' ')
                {
                    conteo--;
                }
            }                

            Console.Write("Caracteres a encriptar: ");
            int encrip = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            char[,] car_encri = new char[encrip, 2];
            string resul = null;
            if (encrip > 0 && encrip <= num_car)
            {
                for (conteo = 0; conteo < encrip; conteo++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Caracter {0}: ", conteo + 1);
                    car_encri[conteo, 0] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (car_encri[conteo, 0] == ' ')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Esta vacio ingrese de nuevo");
                        conteo--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("Encriptado por: ");
                        car_encri[conteo, 1] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (car_encri[conteo, 1] == ' ' || car_encri[conteo, 1] == car_encri[conteo, 0])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No se puede completar la encriptacion");
                            conteo--;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            

            for (conteo = 0; conteo < num_car; conteo++)
            {
                bool bandera = false;
                for (int conteo2 = 0; conteo2 < encrip; conteo2++)
                {
                    if (caracteres[conteo] == car_encri[conteo2, 0])
                    {
                        resul = resul + car_encri[conteo2, 1];
                        bandera = true;
                    }
                }
                if (bandera == false)
                {
                    resul = resul + caracteres[conteo];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Resultado: {0}", resul);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de como se debe de ver:

```
        Numero de caracteres: 4
1: r
2: n
3: r
4: l
Caracteres a encriptar: 2
Caracter 1: r
Encriptar por: #
Caracter 2: r
Ya ingresaste ese caracter ingresa uno nuevo
Caracter 2: n
Encriptar por: #
Ya ingresaste ese caracter ingresa uno nuevo
Encriptar por: l
No se puede procesar ese caracter
Encriptar por: (

#(#l
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para que se te entienda mejor

Comment: Listo, puse el ejemplo de como deberia de verse, con las posibles respuesta y lo que debe de hacer